# Как установить две системы и возможно ли это?

Tags: linux, windows

ситуация такая. Работаю c Windows 10, все отлично. Недавно начал работать еще с командной строкой для laravel. Часто бывают проблемы и за Windows, и приходится много копаться в конфигах. Посоветовали установить Linux, я бы рад, так как раньше сам использовал эту систему, только мне нужен Photoshop , а на Linux ах аналоги слабые, а открывать через виртуальную машину - Фотошоп не понравилось. Вопрос, можно ли на пк установить 2 системы и выбирать между ними. Насколько я знаю можно, вопрос в том как это устроенно и как память разделяется. Хоть и ноут мощный но с памятью тут проблема, всего 256gb ssd, Хватит ли это для 2 систем? В основном у меня всегда 100гб еще пустые...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> можно ли на пк установить 2 системы

Разумеется - можно. Рекомендация: установите Windows первой (т.к. Билл Гейтс ничего не слышал про то, что бывают другие ФС, кроме FAT 32 и NTFS), отдав ей половину диска. После этого установите Linux (любой). При установке инсталлятор скажет  Вам про то, что на диске есть ещё винда и спросит - надо ли её включать в меню загрузки.

> и выбирать между ними.

Только при загрузке системы. У Вас на компе будет две полноценные ОС. Когда я собираюсь работать - загружаю Linux. Когда появилось желание поиграть - загружаю Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, есть WSL ([Руководство по установке подсистемы Windows для Linux в Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/wsl/install-win10)) и WSL-2 ([Инструкции по установке WSL 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/wsl/wsl2-install)).

Во-вторых, есть куча менеджеров виртуальных машин (VMM), включая штатный HyperV.

Обе ОС могут работать параллельно, к тому же в едином сетевом окружении.

Тонкое место - оперативная память. А вовсе даже не дисковая (которая, впрочем, тоже расходуется, особенно на образы машин при использовании VMM).

Comment: Есть, правда, момент - не все приложения под Linux могут работать в WSL/WSL-2 и в VMM, особенно лицензионные.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Насчёт WSL ничего сказать не могу - не в курсе. А вот в VMM - технических проблем быть не должно, если используемые приложением технологии поддержаны VMM, и приложение не старается определить факт работы в виртуальной среде с активным противодействием либо отказом от работы. Трудности могут быть разве что правового характера - скажем, лицензия прямо запрещает использование в виртуальной среде. Во всяком случае, у laravel таких ограничений точно не наблюдается - система с этой точки зрения проста как валенок.

Comment: Увы, у нас большинство (возможно, даже все) покупные пакеты обнаруживают любые VMM и отказываются работать :(

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Вероятно, это некая особенность вашей области деятельности, вернее, используемых в ней продуктов. Которая как минимум должна быть явно описана или в лицензионном соглашении, или в документации (а по-хорошему - и там, и там). Ну что сказать - и такое бывает...

Comment: Да. Пакет Delphi покупали по акции вроде как за 300 000 руб + поддержка 3 года. А некоторые биоинформатические пакеты  стоят от миллиона рублей + поддержка порядка 200 000 в год. Вот и защита у них такая :)

Answer (score 2):

Можно. Например, поставить Ubuntu или любой другой понравившийся вам вариант Linux. Будет установлен загрузчик, в котором вы будете выбирать, какая ОС в данный момент вам нужна.

Однако, если будете серьезно работать с Linux, 100 Гб может оказаться маловато. У нас на рабочих станциях с двумя ОС под Ubuntu выделено 200-500 Гб, из них занято системой 15-150 Гб, в зависимости от установленного софта, плюс (размер оперативной памяти)*2 для свопа (меньше, если памяти больше 8 Гб). Свежеустановленный Linux у нас (свой образ) занимает примернор 9 Гб + своп(8-32 Гб). С другой стороны, NTFS и FAT-разделы вы увидите, свои данные можете держать на них.

Альтернативой, если вас устроит, конечно, может быть запуск Linux с внешнего источника. Это медленнее, плюс, необходимо позаботиться о том, чтобы настройки сохранялись при завершении работы. Некоторые сотрудники на ноутбуках у нас так и работают.